# Parent Control changing DNS doesn't work in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, parental-controls, opendns

I am running a plain Ubuntu 22.04 with no flavors.

Today I realized that my son was looking at some debatable content (not too debatable, but still...).
I checked immediately if OpenDNS was working and it was not.
I switched back to my user with administrator permissions, checked again and OpenDNS was not working. The configuration was correct.
I decided to turn off the Wi-Fi, turn it on again, and connect again to the Wi-Fi with configured DNS and OpenDNS was working again.

So basically, even if I configured something like DNS on a connection if the laptop is turned on by my son, that configured DNS does not work.
If instead I log in as the first user and then I switch to the account of my son, it works.
Is it the expected behavior?

Output of `id USERNAME` is:

```
father@mymachine ~ $ id father
uid=1000(father) gid=1000(father) groups=1000(father),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
father@mymachine ~ $ id son
uid=1002(son) gid=1002(son) groups=1002(son)
```

**EDIT**: the reason I am configuring this is just that my son is 8 years old and I want to avoid web results for misspelled words. Nothing more.
**EDIT**: added info found in comments.
**EDIT**: to add others info found in comments

**EDIT**: in my opinion, this is enough to stop "publishing" this as a way to configure parental control in Ubuntu. Unless someone is showing clearly that this is possible (and it seems to me no one tested it apart from me)

Comment: Hi @user68186, configuring DNS on router is the first thing I tried, but in Italy all telecom companies provide a router on which you cannot change  the DNS. So, to avoid spending money on a custom router, I'd like to change them just on the laptop of my son.
Actually I think as a Standard user he can't create and update a WiFi (no option available).
I checked for sure the "make available to other users" because otherwise he could not navigate and opendns works if I connect first to the laptop and then switch to his user.

EDIT: added info about "make available to other users"

Comment: This explains a lot. Please add all this information in your question. I don't have an Ubuntu laptop to test your setup.

Comment: @Sixro is this laptop in question a laptop running an Ubuntu flavor on it?  If not, then it is offtopic.

Comment: Hi @ThomasWard, I am using Ubuntu 22.04. What do you mean with "flavor"? Thanks

Comment: @Sixro "flavor" means one of the variant Desktop flavors like Kubuntu or Lubuntu.  If you're using plain Ubuntu 22.04 then it's on topic here.  Please edit your post to indicate what version you're using, not just tagging.

Comment: Can you show the output of this command - run as your administrative user OR your standard user - please?  `id USERNAME` (where USERNAME is the username of the specific user on system).

Comment: I edited with the results